# How to clear browsing history in android marshmallow

Tags: android, browser, android-6.0-marshmallow

I'm working on clearing browser history in android. Till android 5.1.1 i.e; lollipop the following syntax is working fine.

```
Browser.clearHistory(mContextUtility.getContentResolver());
```

But, for android 6 i.e; Marshmallow it is not working. So how can I solve this problem, is there any alternative way to clear browser history?

Comment: Are you getting any error??? If yes then post the logcat.

Comment: I'm not getting any error.but, it is not clearing the history.

Comment: Permission has removed to read and write bookmark above Marshmallow (API>=23)   refer this link https://developer.android.com/intl/ko/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-bookmark-browser

Answer (score 1):

Looking at Android source code, it doesn't look promising for you. Notice that clearHistory method doesn't do anything anymore and canClearHistory accordingly always retuns false

```
/**
 * Returns whether there is any history to clear.
 *
 * @param cr   The ContentResolver used to access the database.
 * @return boolean  True if the history can be cleared.
 * @removed
 */
public static final boolean canClearHistory(ContentResolver cr) {
    return false;
}

/**
 *  Delete all entries from the bookmarks/history table which are
 *  not bookmarks.  Also set all visited bookmarks to unvisited.
 *
 *  @param cr   The ContentResolver used to access the database.
 *  @removed
 */
public static final void clearHistory(ContentResolver cr) {
}
```

Here are the same methods in 5.1.1 r1, when they were actually functional:

```
    public static final boolean More ...canClearHistory(ContentResolver cr) {
    Cursor cursor = null;
    boolean ret = false;
    try {
        cursor = cr.query(History.CONTENT_URI,
            new String [] { History._ID, History.VISITS },
            null, null, null);
        ret = cursor.getCount() > 0;
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        Log.e(LOGTAG, "canClearHistory", e);
    } finally {
        if (cursor != null) cursor.close();
    }
    return ret;
}
```

> Delete all entries from the bookmarks/history table which are not
>   bookmarks. Also set all visited bookmarks to unvisited. Requires
>   android.Manifest.permission Parameters: cr The ContentResolver used to
>   access the database.

```
public static final void More ...clearHistory(ContentResolver cr) {
    deleteHistoryWhere(cr, null);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Permission has removed to read and write bookmark above Marshmallow (API>=23).
Refer to https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-bookmark-browser

It looks like you can implement your own browser app and save bookmark locally in your database, but API>=23 on-words you cannot access history or bookmarks from Chrome.